# Running PHP file with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to get a .PHP file to run from a .JS file when the JS file runs (and loops every 4 seconds). The code below does not work. I'm wondering if its to do with file linking in WordPress? I'm very new to JS but doing my best to learn.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval(function() {
           alert("Database updated");
          
     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhttp.open("GET", "tb-user.php", true);
    }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-do-i-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript

Comment: Mike did you try with my method? Let me know if any feedback. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use correct style of http request.
Use this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval(function() {
         alert("Database updated");
          
         var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhttp.open("GET", "tb-user.php", true);
         xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
           if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
              console.log(xhttp.responseText);
         }
         xhttp.open("GET", "tb-user.php", true); // true for asynchronous 
         xhttp.send();
        }, 4000);
});
```